# data augmentation in Keras for large datasets

Tags: keras, classification, large-data

I'm using Keras to train a model for image classification and 'am working with ~50k images. Each image has three channels and size of each image is 150x150. I have to use floats to store the images because of the minute differences in image intensities between the three channels. I'm using a GPU for training but I do not have a lot of memory on my graphics card and neither do I have the monies to upgrade my GPU. I also have to  augment my dataset because my training images do not cover all the possible rotations and translations in my testing dataset. 
I have written my own generator that splits the input images and labels into chunks before feeding it to Keras' data augmentation routine and model.fit(). Below is my code:

```html
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, TensorBoard, LearningRateScheduler
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam, RMSprop
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import numpy as np
import math
import myCNN # my own convolutional neural network

def myBatchGenerator(X_train_large, y_train_large, chunk_size):
    number_of_images = len(y_train_large)

    while True:
        batch_start = 0
        batch_end = chunk_size

        while batch_start < number_of_images:
            limit = min(batch_end, number_of_images)
            X = X_train_large[batch_start:limit,:,:,:]
            y = y_train_large[batch_start:limit,:]
            yield(X,y)

            batch_start += chunk_size
            batch_end += chunk_size

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_image_shape = (150,150,3)
    # read input images and labels
    # X_train_large is an array of type float16          
    # y_train_large is an array of size number of images x number of classes 
    X_train_large, y_train_large = myFunctionToReadTrainingImagesAndLabels()

    # validation images: about 5000 images 
    X_validation_large, y_validation_large = 
                                  myFunctionToReadValidationImagesAndLabels() 
    # create a stratified sample from the large training set. use 100 samples from each class
    y_train_large_vectors = [np.where(r == 1)[0][0] for r in y_train_large]
    unique, counts = np.unique(y_train_large_vectors, return_counts=True)

    X_train_sample = np.empty((12000, 150, 150, 3))
    y_train_sample = np.empty((12000, 12))

    for idx in range(num_classes):
        start_idx_for_sample = 100*idx
        end_idx_for_sample = start_idx_for_sample+99
        start_idx_for_large = np.max(counts)*idx
        end_idx_for_large = start_idx_for_large+99

        X_train_sample[start_idx_for_sample:end_idx_for_sample,:,:,:] = X_train_large[start_idx_for_large:end_idx_for_large,:,:,:]
        y_train_sample[start_idx_for_sample:end_idx_for_sample,:] = y_train_large[start_idx_for_large:end_idx_for_large,:]

    # define augmentation needed for image data generator
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False,  
                                       samplewise_center=False,  
                                       featurewise_std_normalization=False, 
                                       samplewise_std_normalization=False,  
                                       zca_whitening=False,  
                                       rotation_range=90,  
                                       width_shift_range=0.1,  
                                       height_shift_range=0.1, 
                                       horizontal_flip=True, 
                                       vertical_flip=True)  
                                       
    train_datagen.fit(X_train_sample)
    
    # load my model
    model = myCNN.build_model(input_image_shape)
    sgd = SGD(lr=0.05,decay=10e-4,momentum=0.9)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'
    
    for e in range(number_of_epochs):
       print('*********************epoch',e)
       # get 1000 images at a time from the input image set
       for X_train, y_train in myBatchGenerator(X_train_large, y_train_large,chunk_size=1000):
           # split it into batches of 32 images/labels and augment on the fly
           for X_batch, y_batch in train_datagen.flow(X_train_large,y_train_large,batch_size=32):
               # train
               model.fit(X_batch,y_batch,validation_data=(X_validation_large,y_validation_large))

    model.save('myCNN_trained_on_largedataset.h5')
```

In short,
1. I create a stratified sample of my input images to use for the image data generator.
2. I split my input images into chunks of 1000 images and feed those 1000 images to the model in batches of 32.

So, I'm training my model on 32 images at a time, augmenting it on the fly and 'am validating the model on ~5000 images.

I'm still running my model but each batch of 32 images is currently taking 30 seconds to solve. This translates to a lot of hours to solve just one epoch. I'm missing something here.

I've tested my CNN code on a smaller dataset and it works. So I know the problem is not my function to read input images nor my CNN. I think it is how am splitting my data into chunks and batching it. But I cannot figure out where I went wrong. Can you please guide me?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [flow_from_directory()](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) from *ImageDataGenerator* class? It is a built-in in keras and is very good to handle problem like yours easily!
*Flow_from_directory*, specificly, draws your batches directly from your directory and you can perform a data augmentation on the fly.
There are also a couple of example I can suggest you:

- [Building powerful image classification models using very little data](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html). It is a Keras blog post about a problem like yours, very easy to read.
- [cifar10_cnn_tfaugment2d.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn_tfaugment2d.py). A more advanced ad-hoc solution on Tensorflow, defining a specific augmenting layer. Very Interesting though!

I think it's enough to make your network run ;).
I hope it can be helpful, good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I have looked at the links you posted. While they are excellent examples, they do not work for me without major modifications. Although my images have 3 channels, they are not RGB images. I read each channel separately and create a 3-D matrix. So my options are to modify Keras' flow_from_directory to read 3 images and then create a matrix or read images myself, augment and save the augmented images to a folder (like the CIFAR example link you posted). I was hoping to avoid both those options and chose the method suggested in https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/68.